# Subtraction in a while loop. C++

Tags: c++, linux, string, strtok, subtraction

I have this code snippet. I need to subtract numbers from a byte stream (which is already being tokenized by a `,`).

The problem is, when I do `sub = sub - atoi(pchNew)` it gives the sum of all the numbers in negative. Unfortunately, subtraction is not the same/simple as addition and multiplication.

My question is: How do we subtract numbers in a while loop?

```
else if(strcmp(pch, "sub")==0)
{
    sub = 0;
    pch = strtok(NULL," ");

    pch = strtok(pch," ");
    //printf ("------->%s   :",pch);
    pchNew = strtok(pch, ",");
    do
    {
        sub = sub - atoi(pchNew);

        //write(STDOUT_FILENO,"IN LOOP\n",9);
        pchNew = strtok(NULL,",");

    } while(pchNew !=NULL);

    printf("The Subtraction is= %d\n", sub);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

### 'Update:'

Input:

```
Client> sub 4,3,4,5
```

Output:

```
Server> The Subtraction is= -16
```

Thanks in Advance,
Safeer

Comment: So you want to add in the negatives and subtract the positives? If so, then subtract the absolute value of each number.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't get you.. I have a set of integers, I need to subtract one from the next one.. and so on.

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Can you show some example input and your expected output?

Comment: if you need a-b+c-d+e-f... you should subtract as well as add. Or write `sub = atoi(...) - sub;` if you do not care about sign.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you want?  Or are you showing us the actual output and not what you want?

Comment: @Inspired Tried.. It actually worked.. Thanks. Any idea how do I manage signs ?

Comment: @CarlNorum That is what I'm getting now. Simple addition is happening here. (which I don't want). I need the integers to be subracted.

Comment: What do you want the output to be?  Saying you "need the integers to be subtracted" is not a meaningful statement.

Comment: @CarlNorum Sorry but I cannot explain more. A bit weak at English.
Just a simple Example: _What I need is_ = **2-2 = 0**. 
_What I am getting is_ = **2-2 = -4**.

Comment: So for 4,3,4,5, the output should be 4-3-4-5 = -8?

Comment: @Safeer Count the number of integers and multiply the result by -1 if it's even. But the code would be clearer if you calculate your sum with the correct sign from the beginning.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, Exactly.

Comment: @Inspired Got it. Will try working on that. How do I vote up your comment ? Lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to take the first one and subtract the next from it right?

```
else if(strcmp(pch, "sub")==0)
{
pch = strtok(NULL," ");

pch = strtok(pch," ");
//printf ("------->%s   :",pch);
pchNew = strtok(pch, ",");

sub = atoi(pchNew);
pchNew = strtok(NULL,",");

while(pchNew !=NULL)
{
sub = sub - atoi(pchNew);

//write(STDOUT_FILENO,"IN LOOP\n",9);
pchNew = strtok(NULL,",");

};

printf("The Subtraction is= %d\n", sub);
fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. What I have done is:
sub = atoi(pchNew) - sub; (signs are not being managed here!)

Instead of:
sub = sub - atoi(pchNew);